# How to add a check box to a row result

Tags: php, mysql

What Am I missing 
get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'checkbox' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 70

```
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) !== 0)
            {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['aid'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>
                <td>'."<input type="checkbox" class='form' value="1" name="checkbox[]" />".'</td>
                </tr>';
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct this line

```
<td>'."<input type="checkbox" class='form' value="1" name="checkbox[]" />".'</td>
```

like this

```
<td>'."<input type='checkbox' class='form' value='1' name='checkbox[]' />".'</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) !== 0)
        {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['aid'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form" value="1" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
            </tr>';
            }
        }
```